# MVC 3 - Dynamically add text boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a sitution where the user can select which test they want to enter info for.
Example:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

When the select say Test1,Test3, I need to create a form with just these two textbox fields(Test1, Test2).  I was thinking about looping through the options the user selected and then doing a show, hide through jquery but not sure if this is the best way of going about this. Is there a elegant way of just showing the fields that the user chose?

Comment: How are they selected? Checkboxes?

Comment: Yes checkboxes. Currently I am doing a .hide of ones that are not needed.

Comment: Pretty hard without seeing any more code but have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be simple:

```
<ul id="textboxes">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="c1" />                
        <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" /> 
        <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" style="display:none" />
    </li>
<ul>
```

Then your jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('c','');
    $('#t'+id).slideToggle(); 
});
```

Obviously you could have more boxes there.  If you were going to go a more dynamic route, with an unlimited, I would go more of a true adding of the fields.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKVRr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(){ //loop through your checkboxes

    if($(this).prop('checked')) { //if the current checkbox is checked

        var text = $(this).text(); //Test1, Test2 or whatever it might be. Would probably be better to store as a data-attribute on the checkbox

        var $textfield = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text' }).val(text); //generate a textfield with the selected text from the checkbox

        $('#yourForm').append($textfield); //add textfield to the form
    }

    $('#yourForm').show();

});
```